# Why can't I create an AVD targeting Google API's

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The problem I'm having is I've downloaded the Google API's and can't seem to select them as the target for an AVD ?

Included a screenshot to clear up a few things. Like that I've actually (as far as I can tell installed the Google APIS)

When I try to select Google APIS as a target the only option is `Android 4.4 API Level 19`

[image: screenshot of SDK manager]

Comment: Did you try to restart eclipse?

Comment: Wait Wut? Adding API's via the SDK requires a restart of eclipse for the AVD manager to see them ?

Comment: Try it.. if this will not help another option will be to update Android SDK tools and SDK platform tools (but i'm not sure if this will resolve your problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Eclipse will help you!